# Error con contexto de Pop-Up - Unable to add window

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

`Xamarin.Android`: Tengo un `Pop-Up` que solicita al usuario autorización para el acceso a su galería de fotos.
Esto lo hago después de un saludo que funciona con un Task asíncrono.

Todo funciona bien cuando espero a que salga el saludo y me muestre el pop-up, pero si cambio de layout antes de eso me da el siguiente error:

> Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException 'Unable to add window --
> token android.os.BinderProxy@90f74af is not valid; is your activity
> running?'

O el siguiente:

> Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException 'Unable to add window --
> token null is not for an application'

Se que es por un mal contexto, pero no logro sortearlo. Lo he intentado asi:

*(Cabe destacar que el Try-Catch valio madres aca. No evita el crasheo, lo que lo convierte en un error fatal.)*

```
    private async Task SolicitarAcceso()
    {            
      try
      {
         var getthis = Android.App.Application.Context;
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
        
        //Aqui informamos en un mensaje personalizado lo que vamos a solicitar y el por que...
        
        await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(true);
                                    vFrameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.BarraAlertI);
                                    vFrameLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
        
        await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(true);
                                    vFrameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.BarraAlertI);
                                    vFrameLayout.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
        
        //Quitamos el mensaje de aviso y pedimos el permiso.
        
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getthis);
                    builder.SetTitle("Privacidad");
                    builder.SetMessage("Mensaje...");
                    
                    builder.SetPositiveButton("Entendido", delegate
                    {
                    RequestPermissions(PermisosParaPublicarImagenes, PermisosHabilitados);
                    });
                                                                
                    builder.Show();
                                                            
                    });
                                                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                    string LineErrorNumber = "Error";
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Desde que clase estas llamando a dicho async Task? en un Activity, Service?

Comment: @Andrespengineer desde el Activity de inicio ya que es algo que el usuario tiene que (idóneamente) autorizar antes de iniciar a usar la app. Pero si el cambia antes del mensaje a otro Activity (Activity "Notificaciones" por ejemplo) entonces da el error.

Comment: Puedes dar más información sobre como realizas el proceso asíncrono? El código que muestras está en una activity? Como sea, puedes sulucionarlo simplemente poniendo el `try/cath` dentro del `RunOnUiThread`

Comment: Cuando díces "*Task asíncrono*" te refieres a la clase `AsyncTask` o simplemente a un proceso asíncrono? Ese código está dentro del proceso o en una activity? O está todo dentro de la misma activity? Puedes mostrar como creas la tarea asíncrona?

Comment: A la clase System.Threading.Task.Task, ya actualice el codigo adjunto. @SinneroftheSystem

Answer (score -1):

**El error están relacionados a que intentas abrir un Dialogo pero la Activity que lo genera no existe, desaparece el contexto que origina el dialogo**, por esta razón obtienes el error el cual incluso pregunta si tu Activity esta activa (¿Tu actividad se está ejecutando?):

> 'Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@90f74af is not
> valid; is your activity running?'

Como estas realizando una tarea asíncrona en algún momento se esta perdiendo la activity que genera el dialogo, en este caso debes validar si la `Activity` esta corriendo.

Por ejemplo antes de mostrar el dialogo valida:

```
if (!((Activity)getthis).IsFinishing) { // Si la activity no esta finalizando.
 
   //Muestra dialogo.

}
```

En tu código se realizaría de esta forma:

```
  ...
  ...
   RunOnUiThread(() =>
      {
      if (!((Activity) getthis).isFinishing()) {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder;
             builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getthis);
             builder.SetTitle("Privacidad");
             builder.SetMessage("Mensaje...");                                      
             builder.SetPositiveButton("Entendido", delegate
              {
               RequestPermissions(PermisosParaPublicarImagenes, PermisosHabilitados);
              });
              builder.Show();
         }
      });
 ...
 ...
```

Revisa otras formas de validar:

[Android: ¿cómo verifico si se está ejecutando actividad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

Comment: Obtengo este error: -- El nombre 'mContext' no existe en el contexto actual. --. Y si creo la variable mContext de este modo: -- var mContext= Android.App.Application.Context; --. Obtengo este error: -- No se puede usar como método el miembro 'Activity.IsFinishing' no invocable. --.

Comment: Parece que olvidó que en tu código almacenas el contexto en `getthis`

Comment: @Mateo pero ese no es el problema ya que a como le conteste arriba, yo cambie el getthis por el mContext pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Tienes razon Mateo debe ser la variable del contexto en este caso getthis, edite la respuesta.

Comment: No, a como comente arriba, si lo dejo asi obtengo este error: -- No se puede usar como método el miembro 'Activity.IsFinishing' no invocable. @Jorgesys

Comment: Adjunto imagen del error: -- https://ibb.co/8stf6w0 --